# Meaning of json object bundle in Twitter Analytics script

Tags: json, twitter, bundle

I am trying to use the script written by ashleycoxley from https://github.com/ashleycoxley/twitter-analytics-export/blob/master/twitter-analytics-export.py to scrape the data from Twitter Analytics

However, I do not understand one part of the code. What is the meaning of these two lines

```html
export_url = "https://analytics.twitter.com/user/" + analytics_account + "/tweets/export.json"
bundle_url = "https://analytics.twitter.com/user/" + analytics_account + "/tweets/bundle"
```

I've tried to access these urls but to no avail. May anyone kindly explain what's going on here? I've read some where that it is trying to retrieve a json object but I still dont have a clear idea how it goes about

Thank you

Comment: Use the inspector in Chrome or Firefox, click on the Network tab and you will see the two URLs being used once you click on "Export data" in Twitter Analytics

Answer (score 1):

As per comment from author of the script on the page https://github.com/ashleycoxley/twitter-analytics-export/issues/2 , it seems that his script is blocked.

I created a Python alternative that works to this day: https://github.com/philippe2803/twitter-analytics-wrapper